# Issue with C# object mapping with XSLT

Tags: c#, xslt

I recently started working with XSLT, to send emails in my MVC application. I'm trying render the required HTML for email by providing the object hash. but the problem is, XSLT renders the data only when the model assigned is of .NET Framework 2.0, and it doesnt work for .NET Framework 4.0 class (Nothing but EmailPOCO class below). it throws the error 'Function 'UserDetails:get_UserName()' has failed.' . Below are the code snippets. Please let me know how to make this work with Framework 4.0 class.

Mail code:

```
     public void SendForgotPasswordMail(string loginID, string password)
    {
        EmailPOCO email = new EmailPOCO();

        email.FirstName = "";
        email.LastName = "";
        email.UserName = loginID;
        email.Password = password;
        //User myuser = new User();

        //myuser.UserName = "ABC";
        //myuser.EmailAddress = "abc@someemail.com";

        Hashtable objHash = new Hashtable();
        objHash["ext:User"] = email;

        SMTPMail.GetEmailContent("emailtemplate.xslt", objHash, "sampleTest@gmail.com");
    }
```

Object Mapping with XSLT: 
**Error occurs at line "objxslt.Transform(xpathnav, xslarg, xmlwriter, null);"**

```
public static void GetEmailContent(string xslttemplatename, IDictionary objDictionary, string emailTo)
    {
        //var templatepath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/EmailTemplates");
        //var objxslt = new XslTransform();
        //objxslt.Load(templatepath + "\\" + xslttemplatename);
        string templatepath = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["EmailTemplates"];

        var objxslt = new XslTransform();

        objxslt.Load(templatepath + xslttemplatename);
        var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.AppendChild(xmldoc.CreateElement("DocumentRoot"));
        var xpathnav = xmldoc.CreateNavigator();
        var xslarg = new XsltArgumentList();
        if (objDictionary != null)
        {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in objDictionary)
            {
                xslarg.AddExtensionObject(entry.Key.ToString(), entry.Value);
            }
        }
        var emailbuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var xmlwriter = new XmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter(emailbuilder));
        objxslt.Transform(xpathnav, xslarg, xmlwriter, null);
        string subjecttext, bodytext;
        var xemaildoc = new XmlDocument();
        xemaildoc.LoadXml(emailbuilder.ToString());
        var titlenode = xemaildoc.SelectSingleNode("//title");
        subjecttext = titlenode.InnerText;
        var bodynode = xemaildoc.SelectSingleNode("//body");
        bodytext = bodynode.InnerXml;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bodytext))
        {
            bodytext = bodytext.Replace("&amp;", "&");
        }
        SendEmail(emailTo, subjecttext, bodytext);
    }
```

XSLT:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:UserDetails="ext:User">
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>Welcome <xsl:value-of select="UserDetails:get_UserName()" /></title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <P>Dear <xsl:value-of select="UserDetails:get_UserName()" />,</P>
     Your Password is <xsl:value-of select="UserDetails:get_Password()" />
          <BR />
    <P>
   Regards
   MyService Administrator
  </P>
    
    </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>


Exception Details:

{"Function 'UserDetails:get_UserName()' has failed."}

Inner Exception:  Request failed.

   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.PerformSecurityCheck(Object obj, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal method, RuntimeType parent, UInt32 invocationFlags)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.PerformSecurityCheck(Object obj, IRuntimeMethodInfo method, RuntimeType parent, UInt32 invocationFlags)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XsltOld.XsltCompileContext.FuncExtension.Invoke(XsltContext xsltContext, Object[] args, XPathNavigator docContext)
   at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.FunctionQuery.Evaluate(XPathNodeIterator nodeIterator)
```

Comment: It would seem this is a difference in the way .NET 2.0 and 4.0 classes treat properties. I don't know what would be different, but it is an interesting issue. I have added an answer below, but could you check to see if there is any InnerException on the error you are encountering? That might provide more details about precisely why it is failing.

Comment: @JLRishe, Thanks for the quick response. Inner Exception says 'Request failed.' added the Exception details in the main post.

Comment: Seems like it might be some kind of .NET internal security restriction relating to dynamically calling object methods. Is your program running with some kind of sandbox trust level or something like that? [Here's another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623900/csla4-and-net4-aspnet-permission-denied-on-the-client), unrelated to XSLT, where someone encountered the same error after switching to .NET 4. I doubt that question will be much help to you, though.

Comment: i dont think its a trust issue. if thats the case, then is should not work with .Net 2.0 model. and my application not subjected to any sandbox level trust. i tried the steps mentioned in the solution but it did not work. i wonder why the statement "UserDetails:get_UserName()" is works for .Net 2.0 and not with .Net 4.6.1

Comment: I don't know why get_UserName() doesn't work, but given that it's not actually an exposed part of the class's interface, it seems pretty hacky to use it, and that may be part of the reason why you're having a problem. How about adding get-accessor methods to your types and using those? It's a bit redundant, but at least you'd be using part of the types' actual APIs.

Comment: Ok. Will give a try.

Answer (score 2):

Extension objects are intended for providing extra functions that are not available in XSLT, but you seem to be using it as a roundabout way of just passing collections of values into your XSLT.

If you just want to pass in values, you should pass them as parameters, not extension objects.

C# code:

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "User", "the username" },
    { "Password", "t3hpassw0rd" }
}

var xslarg = new XsltArgumentList();
foreach (var kv in values)
{
    xslarg.AddParam(kv.Key, "ext:User", kv.Value);
}
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:user="ext:User">
    <xsl:param name="user:User" />
    <xsl:param name="user:Password" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Welcome <xsl:value-of select="$user:User" /></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <P>Dear <xsl:value-of select="$user:User" />,</P>
                    Your Password is <xsl:value-of select="$user:Password" />
          <BR />
                <P>
            Regards
            MyService Administrator
        </P>

                </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```